# Generic Strategy pattern

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to implement strategy pattern with generic types. I try to create object and the end invoke it but I have no idea how should look like signature of it. My problem is in ObjectProcessor class(Do method).

```
//my code
abstract class Credential {}
class SNMP : Credential { }
class HTTP : Credential { }

//dll
abstract class CredentialDLL { }
class SNMPDLL : CredentialDLL { }
class HTTPDLL : CredentialDLL { }

interface IMapper<T, Y>
{
    T Map(Y input);
    Y Map(T input);
}

class SNMPMapper : IMapper<SNMP, SNMPDLL>
{
    public SNMPDLL Map(SNMP input) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public SNMP Map(SNMPDLL input) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class HTPPMapper : IMapper<HTTP, HTTPDLL>
{
    public HTTPDLL Map(HTTP input) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public HTTP Map(HTTPDLL input) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class ObjectProcessor
{
    CredentialDLL Do(Credential input)
    {
        IMapper <?,?> mapper; // ??

        if (input is SNMP)
        {
            mapper = new SNMPMapper();
        }
        else
        {
            mapper = new HTPPMapper();
        }

        return mapper.Map(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is, you can't declare the mapper outside of the if statement because each of those two types returns a different mapper (one is `IMapper<SNMP, SNMPDLL>` and the other is `IMapper<HTTP, HTTPDLL>`).  There are several options to solving this, but without knowing the rest of your code it is hard to say what would be the best option.  The simplest change that I can think of would be to edit your `Do` method like this:

```
CredentialDLL Do(Credential input)
{
    if (input is SNMP)
    {
        return new SNMPMapper().Map(input);
    }
    else
    {
        return new HTPPMapper().Map(input);
    }
}
```

A second possiblity would be to add a `Map` method to your abstract class and then implement it in each derived class.  Then you could simplify the `Do` method further and remove the need to check for a type (which seems to defeat the purpose of having a generic or a base class anyway).

```
abstract class Credential
{
    public abstract CredentialDLL Map();
}
class SNMP : Credential
{
    public override CredentialDLL Map()
    {
        return new SNMPMapper().Map(this);
    }
}

class HTTP : Credential
{
    public override CredentialDLL Map()
    {
        return new HTTPMapper().Map(this);
    }
}

// Simplified do method, it is now a one liner
CredentialDLL Do(Credential input)
{
    return input.Map();
}
```

Comment: "A second possiblity would be to add a Map method to your abstract class" That resolved my problem. Thank you so much;)

Comment: @MrocznyArturek - The second option is more in line with the strategy pattern. The idea is you have an interface/base class that has methods on it. Then you can pass around the derived classes/interface implementers and call the methods. If you find yourself adding code to determine the derived class type, you have moved away from the strategy pattern. In your case here, it shouldn't matter what kind of credential you are passing around, you just need to know that it has a `Map` method.